# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. while developing a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
Context
service_worker.js
Stack Trace
service_worker.js:0 (anonymous function)

I was working with a chrome extension in nextjs,the above is the error i got.
This is my service_worker

```
chrome?.webNavigation?.onDOMContentLoaded?.addListener(function (details) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome?.storage?.local?.get(["user"])?.then(data => {
      let user = data
      if (!user) user={}
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "runContentScript" , user: user})
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
async function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.user) {
      chrome?.storage?.local?.set({'user': request.user})
      .then(() => chrome.storage.local.get(["user"])).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
);
```

The below is my manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Cold Messager",
  "short_name": "CM",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Send personalized messages to your Linkedin connections",
  "author":"salmanpary@gmail.com",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "32": "icon32.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["webNavigation", 
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*.linkedin.com/*",
        "https://*.coldmessager.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service_worker.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://*.coldmessager.com/*"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "32": "icon32.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Also got one more error.
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
Context
index.html

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="next-head-count" content="2" />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="./next/static/css/41ae2ab17f45a7f0.css"
      as="style"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="./next/static/css/41ae2ab17f45a7f0.css"
      data-n-g=""
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="./next/static/css/aebc3a6e923cce85.css"
      as="style"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="./next/static/css/aebc3a6e923cce85.css"
      data-n-p=""
    />
    <noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
    <script
      defer=""
      nomodule=""
      src="./next/static/chunks/polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="./next/static/chunks/webpack-0b5d8249fb15f5f3.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="./next/static/chunks/framework-2c79e2a64abdb08b.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="./next/static/chunks/main-078c9fa18213e7c8.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="./next/static/chunks/pages/_app-3fa0bc5504ddd5f2.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="./next/static/chunks/pages/index-365fc33054662d87.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="./next/static/c-pvsD9rKOVIPEODjYXfU/_buildManifest.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="./next/static/c-pvsD9rKOVIPEODjYXfU/_ssgManifest.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="__next">
      <nav>
        <div class="Header_navbar__8yDOK">
          <img
            src="/cold-messager-logo-2.png"
            alt="Vercel Logo"
            width="156"
            height="40"
          /><style data-emotion="css 12ykvnd">
            .css-12ykvnd {
              font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
              font-weight: 500;
              font-size: 0.875rem;
              line-height: 1.75;
              letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              min-width: 64px;
              padding: 6px 8px;
              border-radius: 4px;
              -webkit-transition: background-color 250ms
                  cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                border-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
              transition: background-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
                  0ms,
                box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                border-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
              color: inherit;
              border-color: currentColor;
              font-size: 18px;
              font-weight: 600;
              text-transform: none;
              color: #ff40a5;
            }
            .css-12ykvnd:hover {
              -webkit-text-decoration: none;
              text-decoration: none;
              background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
            }
            @media (hover: none) {
              .css-12ykvnd:hover {
                background-color: transparent;
              }
            }
            .css-12ykvnd.Mui-disabled {
              color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
            }</style
          ><style data-emotion="css 32mouw">
            .css-32mouw {
              display: -webkit-inline-box;
              display: -webkit-inline-flex;
              display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
              display: inline-flex;
              -webkit-align-items: center;
              -webkit-box-align: center;
              -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
              -webkit-box-pack: center;
              -ms-flex-pack: center;
              -webkit-justify-content: center;
              justify-content: center;
              position: relative;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
              background-color: transparent;
              outline: 0;
              border: 0;
              margin: 0;
              border-radius: 0;
              padding: 0;
              cursor: pointer;
              -webkit-user-select: none;
              -moz-user-select: none;
              -ms-user-select: none;
              user-select: none;
              vertical-align: middle;
              -moz-appearance: none;
              -webkit-appearance: none;
              -webkit-text-decoration: none;
              text-decoration: none;
              color: inherit;
              font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
              font-weight: 500;
              font-size: 0.875rem;
              line-height: 1.75;
              letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              min-width: 64px;
              padding: 6px 8px;
              border-radius: 4px;
              -webkit-transition: background-color 250ms
                  cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                border-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
              transition: background-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
                  0ms,
                box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                border-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
              color: inherit;
              border-color: currentColor;
              font-size: 18px;
              font-weight: 600;
              text-transform: none;
              color: #ff40a5;
            }
            .css-32mouw::-moz-focus-inner {
              border-style: none;
            }
            .css-32mouw.Mui-disabled {
              pointer-events: none;
              cursor: default;
            }
            @media print {
              .css-32mouw {
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
                color-adjust: exact;
              }
            }
            .css-32mouw:hover {
              -webkit-text-decoration: none;
              text-decoration: none;
              background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
            }
            @media (hover: none) {
              .css-32mouw:hover {
                background-color: transparent;
              }
            }
            .css-32mouw.Mui-disabled {
              color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
            }</style
          ><a
            class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textInherit MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButton-colorInherit MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textInherit MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButton-colorInherit css-32mouw"
            tabindex="0"
            href="https://www.coldmessager.com/"
            target="_blank"
            ><style data-emotion="css 6xugel">
              .css-6xugel {
                display: inherit;
                margin-right: 8px;
                margin-left: -4px;
              }
              .css-6xugel > *:nth-of-type(1) {
                font-size: 20px;
              }</style
            ><span
              class="MuiButton-startIcon MuiButton-iconSizeMedium css-6xugel"
              ><style data-emotion="css z06lvb">
                .css-z06lvb {
                  -webkit-user-select: none;
                  -moz-user-select: none;
                  -ms-user-select: none;
                  user-select: none;
                  width: 1em;
                  height: 1em;
                  display: inline-block;
                  fill: currentColor;
                  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
                  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
                  flex-shrink: 0;
                  -webkit-transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
                    0ms;
                  transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
                  font-size: 1.5rem;
                  font-size: 18px;
                  color: #ff40a5;
                }</style
              ><svg
                class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-z06lvb"
                focusable="false"
                aria-hidden="true"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                data-testid="GoogleIcon"
              >
                <path
                  d="M12.545,10.239v3.821h5.445c-0.712,2.315-2.647,3.972-5.445,3.972c-3.332,0-6.033-2.701-6.033-6.032s2.701-6.032,6.033-6.032c1.498,0,2.866,0.549,3.921,1.453l2.814-2.814C17.503,2.988,15.139,2,12.545,2C7.021,2,2.543,6.477,2.543,12s4.478,10,10.002,10c8.396,0,10.249-7.85,9.426-11.748L12.545,10.239z"
                ></path></svg></span
            >Login</a
          >
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="Pages_container__SbWhT">
        <main class="Pages_main__5_Vsf">
          <div class="Pages_home__buttongroup__vrexC">
            <h3 style="color: black">Please login to continue</h3>
            <style data-emotion="css ycvpij">
              .css-ycvpij {
                font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 0.9375rem;
                line-height: 1.75;
                letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                min-width: 64px;
                padding: 8px 22px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                -webkit-transition: background-color 250ms
                    cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                  box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                  border-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                  color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
                transition: background-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
                    0ms,
                  box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                  border-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                  color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #1976d2;
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                  0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                  0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
                background-color: #ffcc4b !important;
                color: black;
                width: 200px;
                text-transform: none;
                margin-top: 10px;
                font-weight: 700;
              }
              .css-ycvpij:hover {
                -webkit-text-decoration: none;
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: #1565c0;
                box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                  0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                  0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
              }
              @media (hover: none) {
                .css-ycvpij:hover {
                  background-color: #1976d2;
                }
              }
              .css-ycvpij:active {
                box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                  0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                  0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
              }
              .css-ycvpij.Mui-focusVisible {
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                  0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                  0px 1px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
              }
              .css-ycvpij.Mui-disabled {
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
                box-shadow: none;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
              }</style
            ><style data-emotion="css mffx5c">
              .css-mffx5c {
                display: -webkit-inline-box;
                display: -webkit-inline-flex;
                display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
                display: inline-flex;
                -webkit-align-items: center;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
                -webkit-box-pack: center;
                -ms-flex-pack: center;
                -webkit-justify-content: center;
                justify-content: center;
                position: relative;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
                background-color: transparent;
                outline: 0;
                border: 0;
                margin: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
                padding: 0;
                cursor: pointer;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
                vertical-align: middle;
                -moz-appearance: none;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                -webkit-text-decoration: none;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: inherit;
                font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 0.9375rem;
                line-height: 1.75;
                letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                min-width: 64px;
                padding: 8px 22px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                -webkit-transition: background-color 250ms
                    cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                  box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                  border-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                  color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
                transition: background-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
                    0ms,
                  box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                  border-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
                  color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #1976d2;
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                  0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                  0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
                background-color: #ffcc4b !important;
                color: black;
                width: 200px;
                text-transform: none;
                margin-top: 10px;
                font-weight: 700;
              }
              .css-mffx5c::-moz-focus-inner {
                border-style: none;
              }
              .css-mffx5c.Mui-disabled {
                pointer-events: none;
                cursor: default;
              }
              @media print {
                .css-mffx5c {
                  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
                  color-adjust: exact;
                }
              }
              .css-mffx5c:hover {
                -webkit-text-decoration: none;
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: #1565c0;
                box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                  0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                  0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
              }
              @media (hover: none) {
                .css-mffx5c:hover {
                  background-color: #1976d2;
                }
              }
              .css-mffx5c:active {
                box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                  0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                  0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
              }
              .css-mffx5c.Mui-focusVisible {
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                  0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                  0px 1px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
              }
              .css-mffx5c.Mui-disabled {
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
                box-shadow: none;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
              }</style
            ><a
              class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeLarge MuiButton-containedSizeLarge MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeLarge MuiButton-containedSizeLarge css-mffx5c"
              tabindex="0"
              href="https://www.coldmessager.com/"
              target="_blank"
              ><style data-emotion="css wth0qt">
                .css-wth0qt {
                  display: inherit;
                  margin-right: 8px;
                  margin-left: -4px;
                }
                .css-wth0qt > *:nth-of-type(1) {
                  font-size: 22px;
                }</style
              ><span
                class="MuiButton-startIcon MuiButton-iconSizeLarge css-wth0qt"
                ><style data-emotion="css vubbuv">
                  .css-vubbuv {
                    -webkit-user-select: none;
                    -moz-user-select: none;
                    -ms-user-select: none;
                    user-select: none;
                    width: 1em;
                    height: 1em;
                    display: inline-block;
                    fill: currentColor;
                    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
                    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
                    flex-shrink: 0;
                    -webkit-transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
                      0ms;
                    transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
                    font-size: 1.5rem;
                  }</style
                ><svg
                  class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-vubbuv"
                  focusable="false"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  data-testid="LoginIcon"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M11 7 9.6 8.4l2.6 2.6H2v2h10.2l-2.6 2.6L11 17l5-5zm9 12h-8v2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-8v2h8z"
                  ></path></svg></span
              >Login</a
            >
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
      <footer class="Footer_footer__1IwEk">
        <h5>
          ©
          <a href="https://www.coldmessager.com" target="_blank"
            >Cold Messager</a
          >
        </h5>
        <div class="Footer_footer__iconscontainer__j6F7c">
          <a
            href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/cold-messager/?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_search_srp_companies%3BXVyiHlHhQL%2BQNt7Mz9jsEQ%3D%3D"
            target="_blank"
            class="Footer_footer__icons__O_jy6"
            ><svg
              stroke="currentColor"
              fill="currentColor"
              stroke-width="0"
              viewBox="0 0 448 512"
              class="Footer_footer__icons_icon__mwQTl"
              height="1em"
              width="1em"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                d="M416 32H31.9C14.3 32 0 46.5 0 64.3v383.4C0 465.5 14.3 480 31.9 480H416c17.6 0 32-14.5 32-32.3V64.3c0-17.8-14.4-32.3-32-32.3zM135.4 416H69V202.2h66.5V416zm-33.2-243c-21.3 0-38.5-17.3-38.5-38.5S80.9 96 102.2 96c21.2 0 38.5 17.3 38.5 38.5 0 21.3-17.2 38.5-38.5 38.5zm282.1 243h-66.4V312c0-24.8-.5-56.7-34.5-56.7-34.6 0-39.9 27-39.9 54.9V416h-66.4V202.2h63.7v29.2h.9c8.9-16.8 30.6-34.5 62.9-34.5 67.2 0 79.7 44.3 79.7 101.9V416z"
              ></path></svg></a
          ><a
            href="https://twitter.com/ColdM13955"
            target="_blank"
            class="Footer_footer__icons__O_jy6"
            ><svg
              stroke="currentColor"
              fill="currentColor"
              stroke-width="0"
              viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              class="Footer_footer__icons_icon__mwQTl"
              height="1em"
              width="1em"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                d="M459.37 151.716c.325 4.548.325 9.097.325 13.645 0 138.72-105.583 298.558-298.558 298.558-59.452 0-114.68-17.219-161.137-47.106 8.447.974 16.568 1.299 25.34 1.299 49.055 0 94.213-16.568 130.274-44.832-46.132-.975-84.792-31.188-98.112-72.772 6.498.974 12.995 1.624 19.818 1.624 9.421 0 18.843-1.3 27.614-3.573-48.081-9.747-84.143-51.98-84.143-102.985v-1.299c13.969 7.797 30.214 12.67 47.431 13.319-28.264-18.843-46.781-51.005-46.781-87.391 0-19.492 5.197-37.36 14.294-52.954 51.655 63.675 129.3 105.258 216.365 109.807-1.624-7.797-2.599-15.918-2.599-24.04 0-57.828 46.782-104.934 104.934-104.934 30.213 0 57.502 12.67 76.67 33.137 23.715-4.548 46.456-13.32 66.599-25.34-7.798 24.366-24.366 44.833-46.132 57.827 21.117-2.273 41.584-8.122 60.426-16.243-14.292 20.791-32.161 39.308-52.628 54.253z"
              ></path></svg></a
          ><a
            href="https://www.instagram.com/coldmessager/"
            target="_blank"
            class="Footer_footer__icons__O_jy6"
            ><svg
              stroke="currentColor"
              fill="currentColor"
              stroke-width="0"
              viewBox="0 0 448 512"
              class="Footer_footer__icons_icon__mwQTl"
              height="1em"
              width="1em"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                d="M224.1 141c-63.6 0-114.9 51.3-114.9 114.9s51.3 114.9 114.9 114.9S339 319.5 339 255.9 287.7 141 224.1 141zm0 189.6c-41.1 0-74.7-33.5-74.7-74.7s33.5-74.7 74.7-74.7 74.7 33.5 74.7 74.7-33.6 74.7-74.7 74.7zm146.4-194.3c0 14.9-12 26.8-26.8 26.8-14.9 0-26.8-12-26.8-26.8s12-26.8 26.8-26.8 26.8 12 26.8 26.8zm76.1 27.2c-1.7-35.9-9.9-67.7-36.2-93.9-26.2-26.2-58-34.4-93.9-36.2-37-2.1-147.9-2.1-184.9 0-35.8 1.7-67.6 9.9-93.9 36.1s-34.4 58-36.2 93.9c-2.1 37-2.1 147.9 0 184.9 1.7 35.9 9.9 67.7 36.2 93.9s58 34.4 93.9 36.2c37 2.1 147.9 2.1 184.9 0 35.9-1.7 67.7-9.9 93.9-36.2 26.2-26.2 34.4-58 36.2-93.9 2.1-37 2.1-147.8 0-184.8zM398.8 388c-7.8 19.6-22.9 34.7-42.6 42.6-29.5 11.7-99.5 9-132.1 9s-102.7 2.6-132.1-9c-19.6-7.8-34.7-22.9-42.6-42.6-11.7-29.5-9-99.5-9-132.1s-2.6-102.7 9-132.1c7.8-19.6 22.9-34.7 42.6-42.6 29.5-11.7 99.5-9 132.1-9s102.7-2.6 132.1 9c19.6 7.8 34.7 22.9 42.6 42.6 11.7 29.5 9 99.5 9 132.1s2.7 102.7-9 132.1z"
              ></path></svg
          ></a>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
      {
        "props": { "pageProps": {} },
        "page": "/",
        "query": {},
        "buildId": "c-pvsD9rKOVIPEODjYXfU",
        "nextExport": true,
        "autoExport": true,
        "isFallback": false,
        "scriptLoader": []
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- tried try catch in serice_worker